# How to change multiple backgrounds in a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, background, background-image

I have designed a game where In the first page I ask the name of the user( background used- bgimg1)

On the click of a certain button, I go to the next page(I changed the background again)  What I tried to do this was background(bgimg2) and I also tried putting [changeImage and changeAnimation, no error and still did not work], so I tried putting bgimg = bgimg2, It worked!

Now I displayed another button, and on the click of the button I called a function (name - attack),

In the function I tried to use bgimg2 = bgimg3;

It did not work, what should I do to change the background again, please suggest how to change the background, I think maybe if I preload all the images in the same variable, then how will I display different backgrounds in different functions;

**Code**

```js
function preload() {
    bgimg  = loadImage("images/LayoutGH.png");
    bgimg2 = loadImage("Screen 1/image.jpg");
    bgimg3 = loadImage("Attack/attackButtonbg.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a css class with each images, and change on your command

```js
(function ()
  { 
  const bgClass  = [ 'bg1', 'bg2', 'bg3' ] 
    ,   btChange = document.getElementById('bt-bg')
    ;
  let noBg = 0;
  document.body.className = bgClass[noBg];
  
  btChange.onclick=_=>
    {
    noBg = ++noBg %3;
    document.body.className = bgClass[noBg];
    }
  })();
```

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.bg1 { background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/251/500/300.jpg); }
.bg2 { background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/259/500/300.jpg); }
.bg3 { background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/254/500/300.jpg); }
```

```html
<button id='bt-bg'> change </button>
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this with javascript, as the buttons I have created are made from javascript, I do not know css

Comment: @TanzeelRahman don't be afraid, this is just basic css.